# Change locale yandexMapKit 4.0 Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, yandex, yandex-mapkit

Is there any way to change locale in runtime in *mapkit 4.0*?

Using `I18nManagerFactory.setLocale()` do nothing.

In my app language changes at runtime for application and `MapKitFactory.setLocale` crushes with error

> setApiKey() should be called before initialize()!

when activity restarting

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly are you calling the setter? Try inside the onCreate method before initializing the activity.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        I18nManagerFactory.setLocale();
        ...


    }
```